# PostgreSQL query returning all "reference" columns in a table

Tags: postgresql

Wondering how to use `information_schema` to query a single table for all the references it has defined on it.

```
create table article(
  id varchar(255),
  photo int references photos
)

select references from information_schema where table_name = 'article'
```

Hoping for something like that to list out `photo` since it's the only reference column in that table.

Comment: By reference you mean all the columns that have a constraint?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi updated the question with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below.

`information_schema.table_constraints` will contain all the constraints with the constraint type and `information_schema.key_column_usage` will contain the column names and constraint names etc.

[**KEY COLUMN USAGE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-key-column-usage.html)

[**TABLE CONSTRAINTS**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-table-constraints.html)

So, in order to get the column name, you would have to join both and get your desired output.

```
SELECT col.column_name
FROM

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage AS col
INNER JOIN
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints AS constr

ON col.constraint_name = constr.constraint_name
AND col.table_name = <YOUR TABLE NAME>
AND constr.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND constr.table_catalog = <YOUR DATABASE NAME>
AND constr.table_schema = 'public';
```

Comment: `select col.column_name from information_schema.key_column_usage as col inner join information_schema.table_constraints as constr on col.constraint_name = constr.constraint_name and constr.table_name = "article" and constr.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' and constr.table_schema = 'public'` results in `error: column "article" does not exist`.

Comment: It should be `'article'` in single quotes. Also make sure the article table is already created.